# what is it called "a narrow plastic strip that can be bendable. It can stay fixed at the position that it is bent and is used for tying things"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

When you buy an electric equipment such as a phone or headphones, etc. You often see the cables of the equipment are tied into a bunch using "**a narrow plastic strip that can be bendable**". The strip can stay fixed at the position that it is bent.

See these pictures.

[image]

[image]

**What is it called?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you desribed is called a [twist tie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twist_tie).

Comment: one question, we can use any piece of string to tie a bread bag right? In that case, would we say it generally "a tie"?

Comment: @Tom Yes, that sounds natural.

Answer (score 1):

The kind that are plastic or paper molded around a thin metal wire are called "twist ties".
[Wikipedia: twist tie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twist_tie)